# Definition: Length of an Interval (Convex Set) in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I think I know the answer, but I'm looking for a reference that confirms it.

A "proper" interval of an ordered set X as defined by Munkres Topology p.84 is a set limited by $a, b \in X$ with $a < b$ and contains all points $x \in X$ with $ a \lt/\le x \lt/\le b$ with $\lt/\le$ giving open, closed, or half-open intervals.

Other authors extend the usage of an interval of $\mathbb R$ to include all types of convex sets. So as well as the four "proper" intervals they add the four rays (upward / downward pointing, open/closed), $\mathbb R$ itself, singleton sets and the empty set.

By my understanding, the length of a "proper" interval is the difference of its sup and inf (i.e. $b - a$ whether present in the set or not); the length of singletons and the empty set is zero; and the length of $\mathbb R$ and the rays is $\infty$.

Maths is a subject of precision, and as noted **I'm looking for an authoritative confirmation (or correction).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of mathematics that deals with concepts like "length" is called **[Measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))**.

Measure theory takes a family of sets that satisfies some properties (called a *$\sigma$-algebra* and assigns a "measure" to each of the sets in the family.

A very specific measure called the *[Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)* measure is very often used on sets of $\mathbb R$, and this particular measure defines the length of an interval $[a,b]$ as $b-a$, so yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually reading Royden & Fitzpatrick, C.2 dealing with Lebesgue measure. They slip in a definition for length p.29 that covers everything except the empty set. For the empty set one may argue that $\emptyset = (a,a) $ and so length $=0$, or maybe $\emptyset = (1, -1) $ and length = $-2$. As I noted, I can guess the answer - it's just a confirmation.

Comment: ... And,  I think that length of an interval is more basic than measure theory. It doesn't seem to need any measure constructs for its definition.

Comment: @TomCollinge The length of an interval is more basic than measure theory in the sense that measure theory also deals with measures of sets in $\mathbb R^n$ (so, surface area in $\mathbb R^2$, volumne in $\mathbb R^3$ and so on), it deals with sets that are not intervals (for example, the Cantor set), and it also covers sets other than $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Maths may be a subject of precision, but it is not a subject of authority. Better than authoritative confirmation, you can verify for yourself what the length of the empty set must be, by applying some of the basic abstract properties that are expected of length.

For example, two of the basic properties of length are:

1. Given an interval $I$, we have $\text{Length}(I) \ge 0$.
2. Given two intervals, if $I \subset J$ then $\text{Length}(I) \le \text{Length}(J)$.

So if you admit the emptyset $\emptyset$ into the pantheon of intervals, then for any interval $I$, since $\emptyset \subset I$ we may apply property 2 to conclude 
$$\text{Length}(\emptyset) \le \text{Length}(I)
$$
From the existence of intervals of any positive length $r$, such as $I=(0,r)$, we conclude that
$$\text{Length}(\emptyset) \le 0
$$
Then from property 1 we have 
$$\text{Length}(\emptyset) \ge 0
$$

Putting these together, we deduce $\text{Length}(\emptyset)=0$.

By the way, the negative number $-2$ cannot be the length of anything.  When you wrote that the length of $(1,-1)$ can be $-2$, you were misapplying the length formula, which only applies to intervals of the form $(a,b)$ where $a<b$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. the misapplication was deliberate: since some deem it reasonable to consider a singleton [a, a] as an interval with length a - a = 0, why not carry on ?